# How to have a clock running above a while loop in the code of a guess-the-word game?

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, concurrency, clock

Here is my incomplete and unorganized program of a guess-the-word game which prompts the user to guess a letter until the blanks are all filled. However, if happened that after a minute and the player didn't yet guess the word, the game is over. My problem is how can I have a clock running at the uppermost right corner while the loop of the actual game is running too? I shouldn't break the clock (which is also inside a loop) because that will remind the player on how long he has been guessing the word at a moment.
Can I fix this by threading alone? If so, can I ask for any demonstration?

```
import random
from newfile import word_lists
from time import sleep, 
strftime, time
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os


def timer():
    h = 0
    m = 0
    s = 0
    g = input('Start? ')
    if g == 'Y':
        while True:  
 sys.stdout.write(f'\r{h:0>2}:{m:0>2}:{s:0>2}\r')
        sleep(1)
        s += 1
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if s == 60:
            s = 0
            m += 1
        if m == 60:
            m = 0
            h += 1
        

def plays():
    guessed = False
    while not guessed:
        word = random.choice(word_lists)
        word_completion = '_' * len(word)
        letters = list(wor d_completion)
        print('The length of the word is ' + str(len(word)))
        gl = input('Guess a letter or word: ')
        if gl in word and gl in letters and letters.count(gl) == word.count(gl):
            print(gl, ' is already in word')
      
      
print(word_completion)
        if gl in letters and letters.count(gl) < word.count(gl) and gl != word:
            print(gl + ' is in the word again')
          
  letters.append(gl)
         
      
  print(word_completion)
        if gl in word and gl not in letters and gl != word:
            indices = [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == gl]
            for index in indices:
                 
   letters[index] = gl
             
   word_completion = ''.join(letters)
             
   print(word_completion)
            if 
word_completion.count('_') == 0:
            guessed = True
        elif 
word_completion.count('_') > 0 and gl in word:
            print(gl + ' is in the word')
    if gl not in word:
        print(gl + ' is not in word')
         
       
print(word_completion)
    if gl == word:
        print(gl, ' is Correct!')
        guessed = True
    if gl == 'I quit':
        print('The word is', word)
        guessed = True          
    if gl not in word:
        guessed = True

def main():
   timer()
    plays()
    k = input('Play again? ')
    while k.upper() == 'Y':
        play()
    k = input('Play again? ')
    if k.upper() == 'N':
        print('See you!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()'''
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?Is it just that the player looses after 1 minute?

Comment: Yes. That's the only way to get the game over.

Comment: I don't think you will need threading.I hope I've answered your question.

Comment: It's great, but I want to display it for the player to be aware of how many seconds have already passed. Actually, I've already coded the timer (see the timer() function) and it should continually run visually while the player plays the game. Is there any way I can do that?                                                 
  BTW, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Giving a general answer,

get the start time of the game when the player inputs 'Yes' and begins the game

```
start_time = time.time()
```

Then in your main game loop check if the minute has passed and *if yes* break from the main game loop.

```
while true:
    main_game()
    if round(time.time()-start_time) > 60:
        break
print('You loose')
```

Hope this helps